# ¿Cómo puedo pasar un resultado obtenido de ejecutar un comando a otro comando para que haga otra acción?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

En bash o terminal, ejecuto el siguiente comando para obtener archivos por mes `ls -l | grep 'Jun'` y me arroja todos los archivos creados en el mes de junio, por ejemplo.

Y lo que quiero es que esos archivos de ese mes u otro los mande a una carpeta seleccionada. Trate de hacer lo siguiente sin resultados: `ls -l | grep 'Jun' | xargs mv ../junio`

Por ejemplo cuando utilizo el comando ls -lth me arroja un resultado como el de abajo, entonces yo quiero manipular mis archivos por medio de la abreviación Jul, hora o año de creación a través del comando mv para ordenar según lo anteriormente mencionado.

-rw-r--r--@ 1 Usuario  staff   409K Jul 23 15:59 ../Desktop/ARCHIVOS

Comment: agregar -t después de mv... así: mv -t y me cuentas que pasa

Comment: o  ls -l | grep 'Jun' | xargs -i mv {} ../junio

Comment: te sugiero revisar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/91558/5215609

Answer (score 2):

Trata con `find`, para no utilizar más programas y luego pasalo a `xargs` con su opción `-I`. Claro, previamente debiste de haber creado la carpeta de nombre "junio".

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*Jun*" | xargs -I % mv % junio
```

Lo que hago en `find` es buscar los archivos en esa carpeta, con un nivel de profundidad a lo máximo, es decir, que no busque en subdirectorios. Con el parámetro `-name "*Jun*"` busco que tengan la cadena "Jun", porque pueden decir "Junio" o "Junio1", o como sea.

Con `xargs -I %` lo que hago es que lo reciba por el stdin, cada linea va a representar el caracter "%" y ese parámetro va a formar parte del comando subsiguente, entonces el primer archivo se va a mover de su localización, marcada en `mv % junio` con "%", a la carpeta "junio".

Aunque también puedes pasar el resultado de ese comando (`find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*Jun*"`), a través de un *command substitution*, al comando `mv`.

```
mv $(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*Jun*") junio
```

Comment: No hace falta el `xargs`, Puedes simplemente hacer `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*Jun*" -exec mv {} junio/ \;`

Comment: @terdon Tienes toda la razón, no hace falta. A menos que seas un adicto a `xargs` como yo.

Comment: Mira por ejemplo cuando ejecuto el comando ls -lth este es el resultado que me da en consola lo que quiero controlar es los archivos por mes o año de creación, ya sea borrarlos o moverlos a un directorio referente a su año. 
...........................
-rw-r--r--@   1 Usuario  staff    96K Nov 28  2017 poly.jpg
-rw-r--r--@   1 Usuario  staff   6.6M Nov  7  2017 javascript-chuleta.jpg
-rw-r--r--@   1 Usuario  staff   234K Oct 17  2017 kotm2.jpg

Comment: @user3528154 Tal vez deberías de modificar tu pregunta para especificar. De todas maneras, ¿Haz intentado con lo sugerido en mi respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

En general, es [mala idea "parsear" la salida de `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Es mejor, y mas simple, usar globs directamente. En tu caso, sería simplemente:

```
mv "*Jun*" junio/
```

Por ejemplo:

```
$ ls
file.Junio.1   file.Junio.4  file.Junio.8   file.Marzo.2  file.Marzo.6
file.Junio.10  file.Junio.5  file.Junio.9   file.Marzo.3  file.Marzo.7
file.Junio.2   file.Junio.6  file.Marzo.1   file.Marzo.4  file.Marzo.8
file.Junio.3   file.Junio.7  file.Marzo.10  file.Marzo.5  file.Marzo.9
$ mkdir junio
$ mv *Jun* junio
$ ls
file.Marzo.1   file.Marzo.2  file.Marzo.4  file.Marzo.6  file.Marzo.8  junio
file.Marzo.10  file.Marzo.3  file.Marzo.5  file.Marzo.7  file.Marzo.9
```

Comment: Gracias.
A lo que me refiero es que quiero mover o manipular los archivos según su fecha de creación por ejemplo:

Cuando uso el comando ls -lt me muestra esta estructura en la consola
Entonces me gustaría por ejemplo borrar todos los archivos por fecha en este caso la que se muestra aquí 

drwxr-xr-x@   8 Usuario  staff         272  >Jul 28<  12:44